# How to speed up the following R code

Tags: r

The number of row file "Functions.txt" is 100000, and likes this:

```
7702    2
590     12
1673    12
4782    12
9590    12
824     14
2292    14
2968    14
5560    14
199     15
5926    15
6654    15
3853    16
197     18
1418    18
1879    18
...
```

If the value in the second column is the same, Then the value in the first column are extracted. For example，the first four rows of the second column is the same，the corresponding value in the first column are extracted and do the following:

```
data[590,1673]=1; data[1673,590]=1;
data[590,4782]=1; data[4782,590]=1;
data[590,9590]=1; data[9590,590]=1;
data[1673,4782]=1; data[4782,1673]=1;
data[1673,9590]=1; data[9590,1673]=1;
data[4782,9590]=1; data[9590,4782]=1;
```

The R code:

```
data <-as.data.frame(matrix(0, 10455, 10455))
d <- read.table("Functions.txt",head=FALSE)
n <- nrow(d)

for (i in 1:(n-1)){   
  for (j in i+1:n){ 
    if (d[i,2]==d[j,2]){ 
      data[d[j,1],d[i,1]] <-1 ; data[d[i,1],d[j,1]]<-1
    }else{
      break 
    }
  }
}

save(data, file = "data2function.Rdata")
```

Comment: if the second column is the same as what?

Comment: @Spacedman If the value in the second column is the same, Then the value in the first column are extracted. For example，the first four rows of the second column is the same，the value in the first column are extracted

Comment: what exactly does your `break` do? Is it because you know that values in the second column are necessarily increasing (or not-decreasing)?

Comment: @Alexandre Let the code out of the loop

Comment: well, that I guessed. But are you not missing potential cases (for higher values of `j`)?

Comment: good question, why people voted down?

Comment: @Patric: probably because the question isn't very clear / well-formulated.

Comment: @AlexandreHalm you don't need delete your answer which shows the good hint for `combn`. Try to unique `d$V2` first and then do combination for the results so the number will reduce a lot.

Comment: Please show the exact result for your example input.

Comment: @Patric I agree with your view

Comment: Better would be "If the value in the second column appears more than once", or "for each group of unique values in the second column that have more than one member"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a sparse matrix:

```
d <- read.table(text = " 7702    2
                590     12
                1673    12
                4782    12
                9590    12
                824     14
                2292    14
                2968    14
                5560    14
                199     15
                5926    15
                6654    15
                3853    16
                197     18
                1418    18
                1879    18")

library(data.table)
library(Matrix)
setDT(d)
#create combinations per group
combs <- d[, if (.N > 1) as.data.table(t(combn(V1, 2))), by = .(g = V2)]
setnames(combs, c("g", "i", "j"))

#create a sparse matrix
M <- sparseMatrix(i = combs[["i"]], j = combs[["j"]], 
                  dims = c(10455, 10455),
                  symmetric = TRUE)

#check result:
M[585:595, 1670:1680]
# [1,] . . . . . . . . . . .
# [2,] . . . . . . . . . . .
# [3,] . . . . . . . . . . .
# [4,] . . . . . . . . . . .
# [5,] . . . . . . . . . . .
# [6,] . . . | . . . . . . .
# [7,] . . . . . . . . . . .
# [8,] . . . . . . . . . . .
# [9,] . . . . . . . . . . .
#[10,] . . . . . . . . . . .
#[11,] . . . . . . . . . . .

M[1670:1680, 585:595]
```

You can easily transform a sparse matrix into a dense matrix (using `as.matrix`) if you really need one (you shouldn't).

Answer (score 1):

*I'm not 100% clear on what you want to achieve. Tell me if the following code does what you want.*

To avoid the nested `f` loops, you could use `for` on all pairs of integers:

```
for (pair in combn(1:(n-1),2,,FALSE)) {
    i <- pair[1]
    j <- pair[2]
    if (d[i,2]==d[j,2]) { 
        data[d[j,1],d[i,1]]<-1
        data[d[i,1],d[j,1]]<-1
    }
}
```

Not sure it's faster though, I need to test it.

Another idea:

```
unique_col_2 <- unique(d[,2])
values_col_1 <- lapply(X = unique_col_2,
                       FUN = function(v) { d[d[,2] == v,1] })
for (values in values_col_1) { ... }
```

so, each element of `values_col_1` should be a vector of values of $d[,1]$ which have the same "column 2" values. Then, in `...`, use the above `combn` trick to go over all pairs of such values and modify `data` (now you don't have to use the `if` test).

Comment: Why not testing it first before posting it?

Comment: Good point... Let's just see if the code actually does what the OP was looking for. If not, I'll remove it altogether.

Comment: @Alexandre I test your code. Message：Error in combn(1:(n - 1), 2, , FALSE)

Comment: @Alexandre  Message: Error in combn(1:(n - 1), 2, , FALSE) : vector size cannot be NA

Comment: @Alexandre The number of combination is 100000*(100000-1)/2 and is  very large